# Have a single page vertical sectioned website, at the same time, have some sections(div) have horizontal section (div) sliders

Tags: javascript, html, css, sliders

[Please see this website as an example](http://www.smokeybones.com/)
The landing page, has four sliders, which are each separate divs respectively, but at the same time the whole webpage has separate vertical sections.
I know how to do the vertical bit, standard CSS and HTML. however, how do I go about sliding between horizontal divs on one section?

Comment: can you not use the jquery slideshow component ? something like jcarousal as in http://www.holytour.in ?

Comment: well the animation you see there can be slide horizontal or slide vertical too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a div with 100% width and overflow:hidden and position: relative (let's call it 'section')

inside that div put another div with width 400% and position: absolute (let's call it 'wrapper')

then put the 4 slides inside that div with a width of 25% and float: left

then you can scroll the slides by changing the left value of 'wrapper' to move it inside the 'section'

if you set left: 0% you are on the first slide, -25% and you are on the second, -50% and you are on the third, -75% and you are on the forth

you can even animate that $('#wrapper').animate({left: '-25%'},'normal')

Comment: this sounds like a decent solution. Ishall give it a try